# Is there an other way for it?

Tags: arithmetic

Consider two equations:

> $x+y=2$
> $y+z=4$

Find the value of $(x+z)$.
($x,y,z$ all are positive real numbers)

**My Approach:**
$\because x+y=2 \Longrightarrow y=0$ or $y=1$.

**Case 1:**
taking $y=0$$ \Longrightarrow$
 $x=2$ ; $z=4$.
$\therefore x+z = 2+4 = 6.$
**Case 2:**
taking $y=1 \Longrightarrow$
$x=1$ ; $z=3$.

$\therefore x+z = 1+3 = 4.$

> $x+z=6$
> *or*
> $x+z=4$

**I want to know if my approach is correct or is there more better way to evaluate this ?**

Comment: Why does $x+y=2$ imply $y=1$ or $y=0$?

Comment: i assumed it.....that's why i asked for a better way

Comment: $x+z$ is not determined. You have just two linear equations on three variables...

Comment: i got it...thanks

Comment: You also seem to be assuming that x, y, and z are natural numbers, since you only consider cases 0 and 1, but the problem says they can be real numbers, which include fractions and irrational numbers as well.  There are in fact infinitely many possible solutions for (x + z), with the answer stated in terms of y, such that whatever y you choose will determine the value for (x+z)

Answer (score 3):

Adding the equations gives $x+2y+z= 6$ or $x+z=6-2y$. So for every $y$ you choose you'll get a different sum and all values $\le 6$ can be assumed. So taking these two specific ones proves or shows **nothing**. You can just say that $x+z \le 6$ as $y\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Given
$\qquad x+y=2\space\land\space y+z=4\qquad$
we can start by eliminating $y$.
$$
y+z=4\implies z=4-y\\
(x+y=2)\implies x=2-y\\
z-x=(4-y)-(2-y)=2\qquad\longrightarrow (z-x=2)\\
(x+z=4)-(z-x=2)\implies 2x=2\implies x=1\\
(x+z=4)+(z-x=2)\implies 2z=6\implies z=3\\
\therefore\quad x+z=1+3=4
$$
At this point we can also see that $y=1$ but who cares? Ha ha